# reactJs useRef to add or Remove className

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

How to Add className or Remove ClassName using useRef

code follows

```
const refs = useRef("");
 const clicka =()=>{  ref.current.classList.add('correct')  }

<div onClick={()=>{clicka()}} refs={ref} className="js-choose-answer"><div>a</div>{user.opt1}</div></div>
```

i can Access className Value `ref.current.className` but unable to add

code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef} from 'react';


const Slugg = ({user}) => {
//onClick to set className "js-choose-answer correct"

return (
    <div>
 <div className="__options">
                           
  <div onClick={()=>{clicka(user._id)}} ref={ref}  className="js-choose-answer"><div>a</div><{user.opt1} </div></div>
   </div>

 <div className="__options">
                           
  <div onClick={()=>{clicka(user._id)}} ref={ref}  className="js-choose-answer"><div>a</div><{user.opt1} </div></div>
   </div>
</div>
)

}
```

Comment: Mutating the `.current` property of a ref doesn’t cause a re-render. Use `useState` instead

Comment: but here it loops so not single onClick

Comment: That should not be a problem, you can target each div with an unique id. Posting your full code might get you the right solution.

Comment: @kiranvj please find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `useState`. Set a boolean corresponding to user id which rerenders the elements with classname `correct`

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState({});

const clicka =(userId)=>{  
     setStatus(prevStatus=>{
         return {...prevStatus, [userId]: true}   
      }) 
 }

<div onClick={()=>{clicka(user._id)}} className={`js-choose-answer ${status[user._id] ? 'correct': ''}`}>< 
      <div>a</div><{user.opt1} </div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I usually do this and it works**

```
const currentElement = useRef(null)

const switchClassHandler = () => {
    currentElement.current.classList.add('correct')
    currentElement.current.classList.remove('error')
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div ref={currentElement} onClick={switchClassHandler} className={'global error'}>
            hello
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```